# Postgres ltree has-a-child query

Tags: postgresql, ltree

I have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.permissions (
    "user" varchar ,
    "action" permissions_action_enum, -- 'read'/'write'
    id ltree
);

CREATE TABLE public.items (
    "path" ltree NULL,
    id uuid NOT NULL,
);
```

I want to return all rows that the user has permission to see, a user has permission to an item if he has permission on the item or on one of its ancestors.
for example:

```
public.permissions:
user       |action|id |
-----------|------|---|
1          |read  |a  |
1          |read  |d  |


public.items:
path       |id |
-----------|---|
a.b        |b  |
a.c        |c  |
e.d        |d  |
g.f        |f  |
```

According to the above data, the user has permissions to items (b, c, and d).

I want to create a query which joins the above tables and return all items that the user has permission to `read`, the expected result is:

```
path       |id |
-----------|---|
a.b        |b  |
a.c        |c  |
e.d        |d  |
```

There is an efficient way to search whether `ltree` contains other `ltree`? Or if `ltree` is-a-child of another entry? Something like `*.a.*` in `lquery` but between columns.

I tried to use `<@/@>` but they are only good for checks on root/item:

```
select 'a.b'::ltree <@ 'b'::ltree -- false
select 'a.b'::ltree <@ 'a'::ltree -- true
select 'a.b'::ltree @> 'b'::ltree -- false
select 'a.b'::ltree @> 'a'::ltree -- false
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select i.path, i.id from items i
inner join permissions p
on ((p.id = substr(i.path, 0,1)) or (p.id = substr(i.path, instr(i.path,'.') +1,1)));
```

Comment: But the performance of such a query is awful, isn't it? no index can be used...

Comment: If your id and path is same, indexing will be helpful. Even in this scenario indexing on items will be useful as we are comparing a part of path from permissions table

Comment: same = `last path node == id`? this is true. also, if I understand correctly, your method support only one child. in my (real) scenario a parent may have up to few(let's say 4) children (`a.b.c.d`).

Comment: It will support all the child. That the reason i took the substring of the parent and performing the join